# Android Studio, My Activities are going to the wrong activity

Tags: java, android, firebase

so I am a fresh face to android development, and I encountered a problem which I have been going loops for.

I have three activities here, they are for registration,  I don't want to implement scrollview because it isn't that good looking so I made it to three form activities,

The first activity gathers all info from the XML's and passes the values as via intent to the second activity,
then the second activity gathers all info from it's own XML, and then passes it together with the Extra of the first activity to the third activity, and the third activity together with the first and seconds Extras PLUS it's own values from it's own XML's, finally, saves the values to firebase.

Yes the values get's saved, but my problem is the third activity doesn't go to the Welcome class which is supposedly written on its intent. I tried rebuilding and cleaning but it did not work. I couldn't find the bug to my work, can anyone help me out? any help is appreciated. Thanks

Here are my three java classes, and I will also put in the welcome class incase you might want to ask for it:

**Profile.java**

```
public class Profile extends Activity {

    //DECLARE FIELDS

    EditText name,username, phone, age, birth;
    Button  saveBtn;

    //FIREBASE REF
    DatabaseReference userRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);



        //FIREBASE DATABASE REF
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        //ASSIGN ID's
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profileBtn);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profileUsername);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profileAge);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);
        birth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profileBirth);


        // SAVE BUTTON LOGIC

       saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                addUser();

            }
        });
    }

    private void addUser(){


        String userNameString = name.getText().toString();
        String userPhoneString  = phone.getText().toString();
        String userAgeString  = age.getText().toString();
        String userBirthString = birth.getText().toString();
        String userUserNameString = username.getText().toString();

        //GET USER KEY  FROM INTENT
        String userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_KEY");
        String userEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_EMAIL");
        String userPass = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_PASS");
        String userID = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID");



        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userNameString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userPhoneString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userAgeString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userBirthString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userUserNameString)) {




            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Next!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent myIntent  = new Intent(Profile.this, Profile2.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_KEY", userKey);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_NAME", userNameString);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_PHONE", userPhoneString);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_AGE", userAgeString);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_BIRTH", userBirthString);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_USERNAME", userUserNameString);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_EMAIL", userEmail);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_PASS", userPass);
            myIntent.putExtra("USER_ID", userID);

            startActivity(myIntent);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Please Enter Correct Profile Details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this, Profile.class));

        }
    }

}
```

**Profile2.java**

```
public class Profile2 extends Activity {

    //DECLARE FIELDS

    EditText Address, FSN, bType, Height, Weight;
    Button saveBtn;

    //FIREBASE REF
    DatabaseReference userRef;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile2);



        //FIREBASE DATABASE REF
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");







        //ASSIGN ID's
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profileBtn);
        Address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Address);
        FSN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FSN);
        bType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bType);
        Height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Height);
        Weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Weight);


        //MOVE TO LOGIN




        // SAVE BUTTON LOGIC

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                addUser();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addUser(){





        String AddressString = Address.getText().toString();
        String FSNString  = FSN.getText().toString();
        String WeightString = Weight.getText().toString();
        String bTypeString  = bType.getText().toString();
        String HeightString = Height.getText().toString();

        //GET USER KEY  FROM INTENT
        String userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_KEY");
        String userNameString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
        String userPhoneString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_PHONE");
        String userAgeString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_AGE");
        String userBirthString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_BIRTH");
        String userUserNameString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_USERNAME");
        String userPass = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_PASS");
        String userID = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID");
        String userEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_EMAIL");








        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(AddressString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(FSNString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(WeightString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(bTypeString) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(HeightString)) {



            Toast.makeText(Profile2.this, "Go mamshie!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent myIntent2  = new Intent(Profile2.this, Profile3.class);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_KEY", userKey);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_NAME", userNameString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_PHONE", userPhoneString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_AGE", userAgeString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_BIRTH", userBirthString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_USERNAME", userUserNameString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_ADDRESS", AddressString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_FSN", FSNString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_BTYPE", bTypeString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_HEIGHT", HeightString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_WEIGHT", WeightString);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_PASS", userPass);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_ID", userID);
            myIntent2.putExtra("USER_EMAIL", userEmail);
            startActivity(myIntent2);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Profile2.this, "Please Enter Correct Profile Details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Profile2.this, Profile2.class));

        }
    }

}
```

**Profile3.java**

```
public class Profile3 extends Activity {

    //DECLARE FIELDS

    EditText NPP, PCS, MC, SB, PPH;
    Button saveBtn;

    //FIREBASE REF
    DatabaseReference mDataRef, userRef;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile3);



        //FIREBASE DATABASE REF
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");




        //ASSIGN ID's
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profileBtn);
        NPP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.previous);
        PCS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.previouscs);
        MC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.miscar);
        SB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.stillbirth);
        PPH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post);


        //MOVE TO LOGIN




        // SAVE BUTTON LOGIC

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                addUser();
            }
        });
    }

    private void addUser(){





        String NoPrevPregnancies = NPP.getText().toString();
        String PreviousCS  = PCS.getText().toString();
        String Miscarriages = MC.getText().toString();
        String Stillbirth  = SB.getText().toString();
        String PostPartumHem = PPH.getText().toString();

        //GET USER KEY  FROM INTENT
        String userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_KEY");
        String userEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_EMAIL");
        String userPass = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_PASSWORD");
        String userID = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID");
        String userNameString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
        String userPhoneString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_PHONE");
        String userAgeString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_AGE");
        String userBirthString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_BIRTH");
        String userUserNameString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_USERNAME");
        String AddressString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ADDRESS");
        String FSNString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_FSN");
        String bTypeString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_BTYPE");
        String HeightString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_HEIGHT");
        String WeightString = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_WEIGHT");


        mDataRef = userRef.child(userNameString);






        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(PreviousCS) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(NoPrevPregnancies) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(PostPartumHem) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(Miscarriages) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(Stillbirth)) {



            User3 user = new User3(PreviousCS, NoPrevPregnancies, PostPartumHem, Miscarriages, Stillbirth);



            userRef.child(userNameString).setValue(user);
            mDataRef.child("USER_KEY").setValue(userKey);
            mDataRef.child("USER_PASS").setValue(userPass);//
            mDataRef.child("USER_ID").setValue(userID);//
            mDataRef.child("USER_NAME").setValue(userNameString);//
            mDataRef.child("USER_PHONE").setValue(userPhoneString);
            mDataRef.child("USER_AGE").setValue(userAgeString);
            mDataRef.child("USER_BIRTH").setValue(userBirthString);
            mDataRef.child("USER_USERNAME").setValue(userUserNameString);//
            mDataRef.child("USER_ADDRESS").setValue(AddressString);
            mDataRef.child("USER_FSN").setValue(FSNString);
            mDataRef.child("USER_BTYPE").setValue(bTypeString);
            mDataRef.child("USER_HEIGHT").setValue(HeightString);
            mDataRef.child("USER_WEIGHT").setValue(WeightString);
            mDataRef.child("USER_EMAIL").setValue(userEmail);//



            Toast.makeText(Profile3.this, "User Details Completed and Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent myIntent1  = new Intent(Profile3.this, Welcome.class);

            myIntent1.putExtra("USER_KEY", userKey);
            myIntent1.putExtra("USER_EMAIL", userEmail);
            myIntent1.putExtra("USER_PHONE", userPhoneString);
            myIntent1.putExtra("USER_BIRTH", userBirthString);
            myIntent1.putExtra("USER_USERNAME", userUserNameString);
            myIntent1.putExtra("USER_NAME", userNameString);
            myIntent1.putExtra("USER_AGE", userAgeString);
            myIntent1.putExtra("USER_ID", userID);

            startActivity(myIntent1);



        } else {

            Toast.makeText(Profile3.this, "Please Enter Correct Profile Details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Profile3.this, Profile3.class));

        }
    }

}
```

**My welcome activity which gets some data and shows it**

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = "ViewDatabase";
    //ADD FIREBASE STUFF



    //DECLARE FIELDS
    Button outBtn;
    TextView welcome;
    private DatabaseReference myRef, mDataRef, userRef;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private String userIDPassed;
    private String userID;
    private String userKey;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;




    private ListView mListView;

    //FIREBASE AUTH FIELDS
    private FirebaseAuth nAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener nAuthlistener;



    //GET USER KEY  FROM INTENT


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);


        //DRAWER LAYOUT
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);


        //ASSIGN IDS
        outBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
        welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelcomeName);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


        //ASSIGN INSTANCE
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        nAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        FirebaseUser User = nAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = User.getUid();

//navigation Drawer
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
            { switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case(R.id.nav_account): Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity);
                    break;

                case(R.id.nav_exercises): Intent accountActivity1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Video.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity1);
                    break;

                case(R.id.nav_tips): Intent accountActivity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Image.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity2);
                    break;

                case(R.id.nav_scheduler): Intent accountActivity3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalendarActivity.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity3);
                    break;
                case(R.id.nav_logout): Intent accountActivity4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity4);
                    finish();
                    break;
                case(R.id.nav_settings): Intent accountActivity5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Profile.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity5);
                    break;
                case(R.id.nav_info): Intent accountActivity6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Info.class);
                    startActivity(accountActivity6);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
            } });

        //Navigation Drawer





        nAuthlistener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser User = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (User != null){


                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + User.getUid());
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Successfully signed in with: " + User.getEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }else{

                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out" + userID);
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Successfully signed out.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }

        };




        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
                        showData(dataSnapshot);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){

                    }

        });



        outBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nAuth.signOut();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



        //GET USER KEY  FROM INTENT
        String userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_KEY");
        String userEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_EMAIL");
        String  userPhone = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_PHONE");
        String userBirth = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_BIRTH");
        String  userUserName = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_USERNAME");
        String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
        String userAge = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_AGE");
        String userID = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID");


        mDataRef = userRef.child(userName);




        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(userKey) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userID) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userBirth) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userUserName)) {




            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Log.d(TAG, "showData: snapshot: " + ds);
                Log.d(TAG, "showData: snapshot: " + ds.child("Users"));


                //display all info taken


                Log.d(TAG, "showData: USER_NAME: " + userName);
                Log.d(TAG, "showData: USER_AGE: " + userAge);
                Log.d(TAG, "showData: USER_BIRTH: " + userBirth);
                Log.d(TAG, "showData: USER_PHONE: " + userPhone);
                Log.d(TAG, "showData: USER_USERNAME: " + userUserName);

                ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
                array.add(userName);
                array.add(userAge);
                array.add(userBirth);
                array.add(userPhone);
                array.add(userUserName);
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
                mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }


        } else {


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        nAuth.addAuthStateListener(nAuthlistener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        nAuth.removeAuthStateListener(nAuthlistener);
    }





    //FOR NAVIGATION DRAWER


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    //Navigation Drawer End

}
```

What did I do wrong? Thinking of it as flowing water, I think the values flowed well until the last activity?

Comment: its always going to the else thats why

Comment: @PeterHaddad Hello, I think you should expound so he could understand

Comment: Im not exactly sure what he is doing, but by looking in the code there is else{ in the second activity it has intent(profile3.this,profile3.class). So it is always going there everytime thus staying in the same activity. If he wants to be sure if thats the problem add another activity instead of profile3.class and see if it goes to that activity

Comment: So you were saying that some inputs might have become empty thus redirecting him back to the first activity?

Comment: I can say that from his form the intents are flowing right to the last activity correctly, the if-else statement prevents the user from going to another activity unless he has completed filling up the activity. Even if I want to help I can't be so sure as looking at all activities I can't pinpoint where the problem is. In the last acitvity it certainly goes to welcome.

Comment: @PeterHaddad , I think what he's doing here is getting the extras from his two activities to his last activity where he saves them up to his database. He explained it on the description.

Comment: @Rekt I know he does say it saves to database, but if there is a problem with welcome.class the app would crash but he said onclick its just staying in the same activity. Anw just wait until he answers, probably sleeping last login was (11 hours ago)

Comment: Indeed, I was quite interested with this problem, as instead of using the typical scroll view he divided it into three parts. Looking forward to getting this solved.

Answer (score 0):

in your profile1, change the intent to profiles, profile2 eg

Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Please Enter Correct Profile Details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this, Profile2.class));

and do same for profile 2 and profile 3.

Answer (score -1):

Try debugging by removing your else statements and maybe add them all to the last activity